# How to make an async call back get handled synchronously

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, callback, synchronization, pubnub

I have a situation where I am calling a method on a gem that does its processing asynchronously. I want to be able to wait for the callback to be called before continuing execution on the thread where the method was called.

```
gem.async_method(args) do |result|
    # the callback
end
# wait until callback is called and then continue execution
puts result # somehow have access to the result from the callback
```

Comment: What gem are you using?

Comment: I think it's kind of a 'rule' that you can't ever call async methods in a synchronous way.

Comment: @AlexPan I am using the pubnub gem. @maxpleaner. I am looking for a workaround. The hackiest way I can think of is to sleep after the `async_method` call until the callback is called. But there has got to be a better way.

Comment: Can you provide the PubNub code? I think that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution to this eventually. The gem I was using returned a `Celluloid::Future`. If you call `future_object.value` it will block execution until the value is received.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Ruby SDK `http_sync`

I think you are just looking for the `http_sync` parameter when you `publish`, `subscribe`', etc. PubNub. https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ruby/api-reference-sdk-v4#publish_args

```ruby
pubnub.publish(
    channel: 'my_channel',
    message: { text: 'Hi!' },
    http_sync: true
) do |envelope|
    puts envelope.status
end
```

Comment: Not all of them have this flag. Like the `presence` call.

Comment: Presence is long running not short lived though.

Comment: Yeah, I know but it is the only way for me to do a once of request to see number of subscribers while using the servers auth key